# how to create scheduler which triggers a job at every 13 hours in java

Tags: java, spring-boot

how to create scheduler which triggers a job at every 13 hours in java
for example if it starts at

- 12 am then triggers a job at 1 pm
- 1 pm then triggers a job at 2 am

Answer (score 2):

what about using `@Scheduled(cron="0 0 */13 * * * ")`

EDIT:
you can check [here](https://crontab.guru/) the only difference is that spring has added the first place (first `*`) for seconds.

EDIT2:
you can actually use also `fixedRate`
`@Scheduled(fixedRate="13", timeunit=TimeUnit.HOURS)`

Comment: Your answer is not complete without mentioning the `@EnableScheduling` annotation. And your EDIT2 is much a better answer, I would completely removed your original version, the OP clearly asked "every 13 hours" :)

Comment: Well OP now has more info than needed. Maybe he learned something new ;)

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Boot, you can just annotate a method with the @Scheduled annotation and the main class with the @EnableScheduling.

Examples:

Main class in Spring application

```
@EnableScheduling 
@SpringBootApplication
public class ScheduledDemoApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ScheduledDemoApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

and create a method in a separate class that will be triggered on a schedule:

```
@Scheduled(some cron exp here)
public void execute() {
  // some logic that will be executed on a schedule
}
```

This should work fine.

Here is a good article on how to [schedule a Spring Boot task](https://alegrucoding.com/schedule-a-task-in-spring-boot/).